# Laravel 5.6 + Socialite 3 + Facebook login do not work in Use Strict Mode

Tags: laravel, facebook, authentication

I can not make login to facebook like before.
I have installed Laravel 5.6 + Socialite 3 and everithing works good, but when I try to conected a mistake is always shown
I follow this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyCxc72IH9Y 
and Use Strict Mode is always enabled min 15:00

the complete error is

```
Can´t Loar URL. The domain of this URL isn´t included in the app´s domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your App Domains field in your app settings
```

I set fb app as follow

My App > Settings > Basic > Domains > example.com

My App > Settings > Basic > URL site > http://example.com

and in My Products

Facebook Login > Settings > Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs(always Enabled)

before today I setted "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" to (disabled) and fb login was working good, now, I can not change Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs for new APP

How can I solve this?

Comment: what error are you experiencing?

Comment: https://youtu.be/lyCxc72IH9Y?t=876  I use all the same configuration like the video  but I can not connect to FB, the error is can´t loar URL. the domain of this URL isn´t incluided in the app´s domains, I tried to solve like the video but was not possible, I know fb change it and now  Strict Mode is allways enabled

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Explain what your specific problem is using _words_, not pointing at YT videos all the time.

Comment: Sure, @CBroe, I Explain the complete problem

Comment: I know about the new strict-uri-matching so I found https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/ this article, so my problem could be soved if i use the correct URL using socialite

Answer (score 0):

after read a lot of blogs, i found

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/

to solve my problem laravel 5.6 + socialite 3 + fb I recomend to set fb app as follow:

My App > Settings > Basic > Domains > example.com

My App > Settings > Basic > URL site > https://example.com

Facebook Login > Settings > Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs(always Enabled)

Facebook Login > Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs > https://example.com/auth/facebook/callback

Facebook Login > Settings > Deauthorize Callback URL > https://example.com/auth/facebook